# Entity Framework Interceptor to set Id field of patricular entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my current project i am working with the database which has very strange table structure (All Id Fields in most tables are marked as not nullable and primary while there is not auto increment increment enabled for them those Id fields need to be unique as well).

unfortunately there is not way i can modify DB so i find another why to handle my problem.

I have no issues while querying for data but during insert What i want to do is,
To get max Id from table where entity is about to be inserted and increment it by one or even better use SSELECT max(id) pattern during insert.

I was hoping to use Interceptor inside EF to achieve this but is looks too difficult for me now and all i managed to do is to identify if this is insert command or not.

Can someone help me through my way on this problem? how can i achieve this and set ID s during insert either by selecting max ID or using SELECT max(id)

```
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.OriginalResult.CommandTreeKind != DbCommandTreeKind.Insert && context.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.CSSpace) return;
        {
            var insertCommand = context.Result as DbInsertCommandTree;

            var property = insertCommand?.Target.VariableType.EdmType.MetadataProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "TableName");
            if (property == null) return;
                var tbaleName = property?.Value as ReadOnlyCollection<EdmMember>;

            var variableReference = insertCommand.Target.VariableType.Variable(insertCommand.Target.VariableName);

            var tenantProperty = variableReference.Property("ID");
            var tenantSetClause = DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(tenantProperty, DbExpression.FromString("(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SOMEHOWGETTABLENAME)"));
            var filteredSetClauses = insertCommand.SetClauses.Cast<DbSetClause>().Where(sc => ((DbPropertyExpression)sc.Property).Property.Name != "ID");
            var finalSetClauses = new ReadOnlyCollection<DbModificationClause>(new List<DbModificationClause>(filteredSetClauses) { tenantSetClause });

            var newInsertCommand = new DbInsertCommandTree(
                   insertCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                   insertCommand.DataSpace,
                   insertCommand.Target,
                   finalSetClauses,
                   insertCommand.Returning);

            context.Result = newInsertCommand;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately that concept of Interceptor is a little bit new for me and i do not understand it completely.

---

### UPDATE

I manage to dynamically build that expression so that ID field is now included in insert statement, but the problem here is that I can not use SQL query inside it. whenever i try to use this it always results in some wrong SQL query so is there anyway i tweak insert statement so that this SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE_NAME is executed during insert?

Comment: It looks like you're using `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor`.  Might have a lot more luck with `IDbCommandInterceptor` and implementing `NonQueryExecuting` instead.

Comment: Ok but can u give me en example of how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the next id from the context, and then set the parameter of the insert command accordingly.

```
    void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        var context = interceptionContext.DbContexts.First() as WhateverYourEntityContainerNameIs;

        // get the next id from the database using the context

        var theNextId = (from foo in context...)

        // update the parameter on the command

        command.Parameters["YourIdField"].Value = theNextId;
    }
```

Just bear in mind this is not terribly thread safe; if two users update the same table at exactly the same time, they could theoretically get the same id.  This is going to be a problem no matter what update method you use if you manage keys in the application instead of the database.  But it looks like that decision is out of your hands.

If this is going to be a problem, you might have to do something more drastic like alter the `command.CommandText` to replace the value in the `values` clause with a subquery, for example change

`insert into ... values (@YourIdField, ...)`

to

`insert into ... values ((select max(id) from...), ...)`

Comment: This is great one but the only problem is if master child save is called this will not work plus all tables in that DB has this problem not the particular one so LINQ select is useless as I have no idea what gets inserted there .

This is the only reason why i went through IDbCommandTreeInterceptor which seems to be even more  difficult

Comment: How so?  If multiple tables get updated in a parent-child relationship, `NonQueryExecuting` will be called multiple times, one for each insert statement.  And you can get the name of the table being inserted into from `command.CommandText` and fetch the next id accordingly.

Comment: That sounds reasonable but the LINQ query u wrote will not work because it requires exact type right? This is terrible DB never seen anything like that before.

Comment: is there anyone who might be able to help me resolve tis issue?